# Add loop to setTimeout

Tags: javascript, jquery

JS:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $('#houses div:last').after('<div class="item current-last '+ randClass +'"></div>');

}, 2000);
```

But once a time. I want a loop. How can I fix it?

```
var house = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight', 'nine'];
randClass = house[Math.floor(Math.random() * house.length)];
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `setInterval` instead of `setTimeout`.  The former sets a timer that is called on an interval, whereas the later sets a timer that is called only once.

Also, call the randomization code every time you modify the DOM.  An easy way to do this is to include it in the interval function as follows:

```
setInterval(function() {
    var house = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight', 'nine'];
    var randClass = house[Math.floor(Math.random() * house.length)];

    $('#houses div:last').after('<div class="item current-last '+ randClass +'"></div>');
}, 2000);
```

Comment: Yes, it works. But get same randClass value. I want change every setInterval.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use:

```
setInterval(//insert your function and interval here)
```

That will solve the 'execute only once' issue.

As for wanting to get different randClass values, you need to manage that, do something that modifies the value of randClass, between intervals, to suit you purpose. 
As @Lanello proposed, you could randomize it. Or maybe increment it. Whatever your application logic dictates.

Comment: Yes, it works. But get same randClass value. I want change every setInterval.

Comment: Well, you should be sure that the randClass value is changed in between intervals. What is the randClass, and where does it come from? Perhaps you could add some code to clear that out in your question?

Answer (score 0):

you simply must write a

```
function RandomizeClass()
```

and call it inside the SetTimeout, instead of write it inside, surely you set the randClass value before the setTimeout and then its value never change.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var intv = setInterval(test, 2000);
// you can also clear the interval 
// by use clearInterval(intv);
function test(){
   $('#houses div:last').after('<div class="item current-last '+ randClass +'"></div>');
}
```